# Call different method depending on Bool without if-statement in Swift

Tags: swift, methods

Is it possible to call one or another method depending a `Bool` value?  I wish to do this:

```
var isLocked: Bool
{
    didSet
    {
        // This is not Swift but indicates what I'm looking for.
        self.activityIndicator.(isLocked ? startAnimating() : stopAnimating())
    }
}
```

I'm looking to do this using existing Swift 2 (or 3) language features; without class extensions.

Possibly a duplicate, but couldn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
didSet {
    isLocked ? self.activityIndicator.startAnimating() :
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Swift twisted my mind expecting a fancy construction :-) Is there no way that's closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah. If you wanted to be really fancy, you could extend `UIActivityIndicator`, and write a function that takes a bool and handles the ternary in there (ie. `handleAnimatingState(shouldAnimate: Bool)`). But to me that's over-engineering.

Comment: No, I'm looking for native Swift 2.3 (or 3.0) functionality.

Comment: Then no; my original code is the most condensed you'll get.